# Credentials with WCF service in WP8 application

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-phone-8, soap

I have a WCF SOAP web service i would use in a Windows Phone 8 application.

Here is web.config on my service :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="ersteinb">
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential"/>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint contract="PDAErsteinService.IPDAErsteinMobileService" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ersteinb" name="PDAErsteinMobileServiceEndPoint"/>
    </client>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior> 
          <!-- Pour éviter la divulgation des informations sur les métadonnées, définissez la valeur ci-dessous sur false et supprimez le point de terminaison des métadonnées ci-dessus avant le déploiement. -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- Pour recevoir les détails d'exception des erreurs à des fins de débogage, définissez la valeur ci-dessous sur true. Définissez-la sur false avant le déploiement pour éviter la divulgation des informations d'exception. -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

I need to send credentials when i call my service because he is under a reverse proxy.

I cannot find an other way than this to call my service with credentials :

```
PDAErsteinMobileServiceClient client = new PDAErsteinMobileServiceClient();
client.clientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "foo";
client.clientCredentials.UserName.Password = "foofoo";
client.GetAttelageCollectionCompleted += client_GetAttelageCollectionCompleted;
client.GetAttelageCollectionAsync();
```

With this method, i got an exception like that :

> System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException exception was not handled by user HResult code = 2146233087 Message = The remote server returned an
>   unexpected response: (401) Authorization Required. In Silverlight, a
>   404 response code may be reported even when the service sends a
>   different error code. Source = System.ServiceModel StackTrace: [...]

I'm sure that my credentials are fine, but i'm pretty sure i dont send them with the good way. If it's not that, it can be my security in web.config who is false.

When i try to call this service in a ConsoleApplicationProject, i got this exception :

> System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException exception was
>   not handled HResult = 2146233087 Message = the HTTP request is
>   unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The
>   authentication header received from the server was 'Basic realm =
>   "Foooo" '. [...]

Can someone plz post a sample with a webservice call in WP8 with Credentials ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use `<security mode="TransportCredentialOnly" />` then your problem will be resolved

*Just to note endpoint address is missing in config you provided , i assume you have done so not to disclose your url.*

**Changes in client web.config**

```
<bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="ersteinb">
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly"/> //note this change
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

**Changes in code to call service :**

```
    PDAErsteinMobileServiceClient client = new PDAErsteinMobileServiceClient();
    using (OperationContextScope scope = new OperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel)) {
                HttpRequestMessageProperty request = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
                request.Headers[System.Net.HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Basic " + EncodeCredentials("foo", "foofoo");
                OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties.Add(HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name, request);
                client.GetAttelageCollectionAsync();
                }

//use this function 
private string EncodeCredentials(string username, string password) {
    string credentials = username + ":" + password;
    var asciiCredentials = (from c in credentials
                            select c <= 0x7f ? (byte)c : (byte)'?').ToArray();

    return Convert.ToBase64String(asciiCredentials);
}
```

**Changes in service web.config**

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="ValidatorServiceBehaviour"
               name="WCFServiceLibrary.SettingsService">
        <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="ValidatorBinding"
                  contract="PDAErsteinService.IPDAErsteinMobileService"  />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080/PDAErsteinService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ValidatorServiceBehaviour">
          <serviceDebug httpsHelpPageEnabled="true"
                        includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceCredentials>
            <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"
                                    customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="UserValidator.Validator, UserValidator" />
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="ValidatorBinding">
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Basic"/>
          </security>
        </binding>

      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Hello, i have done everything you said, but i still get this error : "System.ArgumentException: The provided URI scheme 'https' is invalid; expected 'http'. Parameter name: via" and if i change configuration to "transport" i got the others errors already paste.

Comment: It works with a configuration of the RP (he used cookies i dont send with requests) and the security mode with HTTPS is : TransportWithMessageCredential